# Rails persistent key-value storage : Only in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I designed a Rails' App with plenty of models organised in dedicated tables (as it should be).

Recently, I have been trying to extract the hardcoded parameters of my App (titles, etc.) to YAML config files. Although I'm quite happy with this approach, the problem is I am not able to modify them on the fly via the App, only from a text editor.

Now, I have considered using a dedicated database table to store them it, but it seems like an overkill, since  this `settings_table` will have an awful lot of fields, and only a single object.

Basically, what I am looking for is a simple long-lived (as in forever) key-value storage. A Reddis server would obviously be another overkill. It seems like ActiveRecord::Cache::Store could be a solution, although I am not sure about the long-lived part.

### What is the 'true' Rails' way of achieving this ?

## Edit : Data Types

A couple dozens of key->string values, like this:

```
page_title: "My Awesome Website"
full_name: "James Bond"
occupation: "Secret Agent"
facebook_account: "www.facebook.com/007"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having one column for each key you can just have a single column and store the data in serialized format. With this even though in future if you want to add more data there won't be any problem.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize will give you some refer or else you can use to_json and JSON.parse methods as well by considering the data as a hash.

In your case as below
config_data = {page_title: "My Awesome Website",
full_name: "James Bond",
occupation: "Secret Agent",
facebook_account: "www.facebook.com/007"}

config_data.to_json can be stored in database directly and for reading JSON.parse(dbvalue)